# Fragment - change orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, orientation

I would like to know how to known that my Fragment (splash screen) has been already shown before I switched orientation to landscape. I guess that after orientation change Activity is destroyed.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //toolbar ...

       showFragment(new SplashFragment());
    }

    public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack("").commit();
    }

    @Override
    //Menu item icons
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Fragment (splash screen)

public class SplashFragment extends Fragment {

```
public static SplashFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    SplashFragment fragment = new SplashFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showFragment(ContactListFragment.newInstance());
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You could add a boolean into the bundle after your handler has been completed for your SplashFragment.  So when the SplashFragment is called, the savedInstanceState can check if it is true, then skip and show ContactListFragment instead.
Either that or use SharedPreferences and store the boolean in there and check it from MainActivity and do an if () else {} to showFragment(new SplashFragment.newInstance()) or showFragment(newContactListFragment.newInstance())

Comment: Why not implement the splashscreen as activity theme and get rid of the splashscreen fragment, so you can be sure the splashscreen is displayed before you enter the mainactivity ? After that you´ll get orientation from configuration. Please define the outcome do you want a portrait splashscreen in an landscape oriented app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the point you call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

You can find your fragment from the `FragmentManager` by calling

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(/* by id or tag */)
```

And example you can tell quickly was fragment shown by

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(/*Id or TAG*/) != null ? fragment was added to FragmentManager : fragment is not in FragmentManager
```

If you have called remove() method you can't know has splash been shown or not. You can try create a boolean value system to indicate have fragment been in FragmentManager.

Orientation changes at Android does kill activities and fragments. By properly saving your activities and fragments state at

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    //Save your stuff to bundle
}
```

and restoring them at

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ( savedInstanceState == null) return;
    //get your stuff from savedInstanceState
    //Example
    boolean[] array = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("yourkey");
}
```

You can save example your boolean indicators to boolean[] array and know what has been happened in this "global" lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Quote from my comment

> You could add a boolean into the bundle after your handler has been completed for your SplashFragment. So when the SplashFragment is called, the savedInstanceState can check if it is true, then skip and show ContactListFragment instead. Either that or use SharedPreferences and store the boolean in there and check it from MainActivity and do an if () else {} to showFragment(new SplashFragment.newInstance()) or showFragment(newContactListFragment.newInstance())

Example of SharedPreferences:

MainActivity.java

In onCreate before `showFragment()`

```
 [...] // other activity stuff
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean hasShown = sharedPref.getBoolean("hasShown", false);
 if(hasShown)
 { showFragment(new ContactListFragment()); }
 else
 { showFragment(new SplashFragment()); }
```

SplashFragment.java

In onViewCreated before `new Handler()`

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("hasShown", true);
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: Ok, so in your MainActivity.java create a public variable `public static Activity mActivity` and in your `onCreate` method assign `mActivity` with `getActivity();`  now in your SplashFragment access the mActivity using `MainAcitvity.mActivity` which in turn can be used to like so, `MainActivity.mActivity.getActivity();`

Comment: I added in the `mActivity` into the snippet above.  Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: I revoked the `static mActivity` in the answer above and included the `((MainActivity) getActivity())` into the `SplashFragment`.  Where is the error `unable to resolve getActivity()` being produced?